# Setting up keycloak bearer-only client with https keycloak server

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have been trying to setup keycloak bearer-only client.Followed the steps mentioned in the keycloak documentation for javascript adapter. http works fine. With https, I was getting "Access Denied".
Below is the keycloak.json used in the client.

`{
  "realm": "MyRealm",
  "auth-server-url": "https://10.65.107.118:8043/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "edge",
  "bearer-only": true, 
  "public-client": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add "realm-public-key" in the keycloak.json.

The value of realm-public-key can be found from keycloak server. That is going to realm settings , one can find the public-key and copy-paste it in keycloak.json,to be used by client apps of this realm.

`{
  "realm": "MyRealm",
  "auth-server-url": "https://10.65.107.118:8043/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "edge",
  "bearer-only": true, 
  "public-client": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "realm-public-key": "MIIBIjANBgkqh..."
}`

hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I missed the `keycloak.auth-server-url` in the backend .I added it and it worked